# Dynamic CRM 2011 Online Capacity for Big Database

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, capacity

We have our own built-in CRM, but we are planning to migrate to Dynamic CRM Online. Functionality wise we have no problems, however, our system will have Millions of Contact Record, each of them can have multiple Opportunity Records.

Is the Dynamic CRM Online is a recommended solution (performance-wise) for our type of situation? Can it scale to handle millions of records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect so, I believe it runs pretty much on the same hardware setup.

In fact you may see better performance because it runs on the cloud and Microsoft must have some pretty beefy hardware for all their customers; which together must represents millions of records.

I suppose to be sure you should contact them.

The obvious downside though is that you pay by the `gb`. Something like $10 per gb per month.